# How to add pictures to a container Sprite with forEach and progress bar?

Tags: actionscript-3, foreach, loader

I am successful in loading a single image and creating it using addChild(). Now I am trying to load multiple images into a sprite "Container" using a forEach loop increasing the X value for each image so they are displayed in a row. The imageloader is referenced to linkage within an XML document. If I testrun this code, this error pops up at the point when the image is loaded and I try to removeChild() the loadBar Animation.

```
ArgumentError: Error #2025: The supplied DisplayObject must be a child of the caller.
at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/removeChild()
```

Here is the AS3:

```
private function loadBG():void {
    var artGrab:Number = 0;
    var artX:Number = 0;
    for each (var albumData:XML in mainXML.artist[artistID].album) {
        imgURL = new URLRequest(mainXML.artist[artistID].album[artGrab].art);
        imgLdr = new Loader();

        //if you're loading a bigger image or need a preloader
        imgLdr.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,onBGLoaded);
        imgLdr.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onLoading); 
        //add loader animation "All Loader"
        ldrAnim = new AllLoader();
        albumContainer.addChild(ldrAnim);
        ldrAnim.x = artX;
        ldrAnim.y = 200; 
        imgLdr.load(imgURL);
        artGrab++;
        artX + 481;
        ldrAnim.x + 481;
    }
}

private function onLoading(evt:ProgressEvent):void {
    var bytesToLoad:Number = imgLdr.contentLoaderInfo.bytesTotal;
    var numberLoaded:Number = imgLdr.contentLoaderInfo.bytesLoaded;
    ldrAnim.progBar.scaleX = numberLoaded / bytesToLoad;
    var loadedPercent = Math.round(numberLoaded / bytesToLoad * 100);
    ldrAnim.progPercent.text = loadedPercent + " %";
    trace("Loading..." + loadedPercent + "%");
}

private function onBGLoaded(evt:Event):void {
    trace("image loaded!");
    //image setup
    addChildAt(imgLdr,0);
    //now that its 100% loaded, you can resize it , etc.
    removeChild(ldrAnim);

    //use cross multiplying of fractions to maintain aspect ratio
    var origW = imgLdr.contentLoaderInfo.width;
    var origH = imgLdr.contentLoaderInfo.height;
    trace("orig width: "+ origW + "orig height: " + origH);
    //set new width
    imgLdr.width = 481;
    var newH:Number = 481 * origH / origW;
    imgLdr.height = newH;

    //may wish to do positioning AFTER resizing
    imgLdr.x = stage.stageWidth / 2 - imgLdr.width / 2;
    imgLdr.x = 0;
    imgLdr.y = 0;
    imgLdr.width = 480;
    imgLdr.height = 480;
    imgLdr.alpha = 1;   
    imgLdr.z = 0;
}
```

Bless you for reading this all, I don't understand what is causing this error so comments are appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

What's happening is that you have populated the variable `ldrAnim` multipe times, creating a new `AllLoader` each time. When you call `removeChild()`, this works fine the first time (sort of--it will remove the last one you created, whether it matches the image that loaded or not). When you call `removeChild()` again, you're calling it for the same one you just removed (which is no longer a child of the object you're calling it on).

One way to fix this is to use a `Dictionary` and associate each `AllLoader` with the `Loader` for that image. When the `COMPLETE` event fires, you can then look up the `Alloader` based on the event's properties and remove it.

Another solution is to write a Class that wraps an `AllLoader` and a `Loader` and then handles the transition between the two itself when the Loader has finished loading.

That might look something like this:

```
public class LoadSwitcher extends Sprite{
   protected var loader:Loader;
   protected var allLoader:AllLoader;
   public function loadSwitcher(url) {
       super();
       loader = new Loader();
       var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
       loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, switchLoaders);
       allLoader = new AllLoader(loader);//assume AllLoader now has logic to watch the loader for % complete
       loader.load(request);
       addChild(allLoader);
   }
   protected function switchLoaders(e:Event):void {
      removeChild(allLoader);
      addChild(loader);
   }
}
```

Then just create and position one of these for each one of your albums.

Comment: I have been doing some reading about and experimenting with dictionary class to solve this AS3 problem, but I don't understand what you mean for me to try with your proposed solutions.

Comment: The key would be the Loader (or possibly the contentLoaderInfo) and the value would be the AllLoader. When the event fired, the tartet would give you the key, and you'd look up the value that needs to be removed in the dictionary. I suspect you're not to the point where I could explain the other option to you without writing the code for you.

Comment: It would be appreciated if you gave it a shot

Comment: Which one of the solutions did you want?

Comment: I would love if you could tell me some knowledge about an alternate option.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have an array of animations for your loaders to hold with the loaders themselves, then when another `ProgressEvent.PROGRESS` event will arrive, query the array for `event.target` index, grab corresponding animation and adjust that, and stop relying on single-valued global vars once you put a single listener onto multiple different objects!

```
var animations:Vector.<AllLoader>;
var loaders:Vector.<LoaderInfo>;
private function loadBG():void {
    var artGrab:int=0;
    var artX:int=0;
    animations=new Vector.<AllLoader>();
    loaders=new Vector.<LoaderInfo>;
    for each (var albumData:XML in mainXML.artist[artistID].album) {
        imgURL = new URLRequest(mainXML.artist[artistID].album[artGrab].art);
        imgLdr = new Loader();
        //if you're loading a bigger image or need a preloader
        imgLdr.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,onBGLoaded);
        imgLdr.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onLoading); 
        //add loader animation "All Loader"
        ldrAnim = new AllLoader();
        albumContainer.addChild(ldrAnim);
        anomations.push(ldrAnim)
        loaders.push(imgLdr.contentLoaderInfo); // fill the arrays
        ldrAnim.x = artX;
        ldrAnim.y=200; 
        imgLdr.load(imgURL);
        artGrab++;
        artX+=481;
    }
}

private function onLoading(evt:ProgressEvent):void{
    var bytesToLoad:Number=evt.target.bytesTotal;
    var numberLoaded:Number=evt.target.bytesLoaded; // note it now refers to target of event
    var index:int=loaders.indexOf(evt.target); // should be valid
    var ldrAnim:AllLoader=animations[index]; // grab corresponding animation
    ldrAnim.progBar.scaleX = numberLoaded/bytesToLoad;
    var loadedPercent=Math.round(numberLoaded/bytesToLoad*100);
    ldrAnim.progPercent.text = loadedPercent +" %";
    trace("Loading..."+loadedPercent +"%");
}
```

Do the same trick with your `onBGLoaded` function yourself, as a lesson. Note, you have to retrieve `imgLdr` value correctly from the event.

Comment: This answer is great, thank you kindly. It seems to yeild a strange error though:
RangeError: Error #1125: The index -1 is out of range 2.
 at ca.folder.folder::SongLibrary/onLoading()

Comment: Hmm. -1 means that `evt.target` was not found in the array. With these you have to trace what's being put into arrays and what's the `evt.target`. Also those traces might yield valuable info about how and what dispatches ProgressEvents. Another nitpick - if you are reloading the entire library, you have to clear listeners from loaders, this can probably net you this message if a loader that's not in the array sends a ProgressEvent.