# For loops, arrays and movie clips - how to achieve a dynamic system

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am working on a Flash scene that reads from an XML file to "build" up an animation itself.

Reading the XML is no problem, that works like a charm. My issue is when I come to placing the assets (images) on to the stage.

My code is below:

```
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.display.MovieClip;

var xmlLoader:URLLoader;
var builderXml:XML;

var container:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
var assetsArray:Array = new Array();

var bg:Sprite;

stage.addChild(container);

init();

function init():void
{
    xmlLoader = new URLLoader();
    xmlLoader.load(new URLRequest("build_me.xml"));
    xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, processXML);
}

function processXML(e:Event):void {
    builderXml = new XML(e.target.data);

    for (var i:int = 0; i < builderXml.assets.*.length(); i++){
        var image:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
        var assetArray:Array = new Array();

        image.x = builderXml.assets.asset[i].start.position.x;
        image.y = builderXml.assets.asset[i].start.position.y;

        trace(image.x);

        assetArray.push(builderXml.assets.asset[i].source);
        assetArray.push(builderXml.assets.asset[i].start.scale);
        assetArray.push(builderXml.assets.asset[i].start.position.x);
        assetArray.push(builderXml.assets.asset[i].start.position.y);
        assetArray.push(builderXml.assets.asset[i].start.rotation);
        assetArray.push(image);

        assetsArray.push(assetArray);

        var lc:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext();
        lc.checkPolicyFile = false;

        var loader = new Loader();
        loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onImageLoaded);

        var _myURLRequest = new URLRequest(builderXml.assets.asset[i].source);
        loader.load(_myURLRequest, lc);

        function onImageLoaded(e:Event):void
        {
            loader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onImageLoaded);
            image.addChild(e.target.content);
        }

        container.addChild(assetsArray[i][5]);
    }
    trace(assetsArray);

}
```

My XML has 2 assets listed, one 1280 x 720 image for a backdrop and the other is a simple logo that I want to position, using set x and y coordinates.

The problem is that both assets are being added to the same movieclip, despite the fact I am creating a new MC instance inside the FOR loop.

How can I get the assets to adhere to separate movieclips that I can then store in the array (pretty sure I am storing the current MC properly in the array, just happens that the MC contains 2 images, not 1 a piece)

Also, why is it that I cannot access the variable "i" inside the "onImageLoaded" function? It sits inside the FOR loop...

Comment: `container.addChild(assetsArray[i][5]);` this could be simplified to `container.addChild(image);` but I would actually do this:
`var image = assetsArray[assetsArray.push(new MovieClip()) - 1];` this way the image holds reference to the array which holds the MovieClip instance.

Comment: also, why are you waiting with adding the loaded asset to be in the complete event, it is `Loader` so you can add it straight away - no hassle then.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a global variable inside a listener, and expect it to not being changed when the listener would actually fire. Listeners are asynchronous, so you should track which of the loaders fired a `Event.COMPLETE` event so that you could retrieve a correct instance of `image` MC out of those prepared at the XML parsing step, and only then stuff the loader's content inside it. [This my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15605263/how-to-add-pictures-to-a-container-sprite-with-foreach-and-progress-bar/15607518#15607518) has a method of doing just that, the method you should use is similar to the one that's used to retrieve a corresponding progress bar over there.

Comment: Well, you have one array `assetsArray`. Create another array that would contain your loaders, so that loader with index `i` will have to fit into asset with index `i`. Then you get `event.target` within the event listener, run `loaders.indexOf()` to get index, get asset by that index off `assetsArray` then do whatever you want with that MC. You want adding `loader.content`? Sure, call `addChild()`. The rest of the code is accessible by that link in the answer.